# For iPhone OS 4.0 "dateFromString" method of NSDateFormatter returns nil

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter, init

I am using following code & its working perfectly fine in iPhone OS 3.2

```
+(NSDate *)NSDateFromString:(NSString *)dateString
{

 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *dateObj=[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    [dateFormatter release], dateFormatter=nil;
    return dateObj;
}
```

But when I tried to use the same code I iPhone OS 4.0 the dateObj was nil.

The reason is :

> `- (id)init` method for NSDateFormatter is only Available in iPhone OS 2.0 through iPhone OS 3.2.
>   It is deprecated in iPhone OS 4.0.

Now what is the solution for that ? How to init NSDateFormater? What's the alternative ?

Comment: We can convert the NSString to NSDate using NSDateComponents like :

NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

[comps setDay:6];

[comps setMonth:5];

[comps setYear:2004];


NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]

    initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];

[comps release];

Comment: But, Now what to do with NSDateFormatter ? Can't we use it with IPhone OS 4.0? if yes then how ?

Comment: just beacuse it's deprecated doesn't mean that it won't work - it just might not work in the future. If you __NSLog(@"%@", dateFormatter);__ after you have called init what do you get? If you don't get nil, this warning is nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: The `-setDateFormat:` call overrides the previous `-setDateStyle:` and `-setTimeStyle:`. Those two statements are unnecessary.

Comment: This is a very common problem, take a look at the [previous answers](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=dateFromString+nil+NSDate+site%3Astackoverflow.com) to see if one of them solves your problem.

Comment: I am having headaches with NSNumberFormatter for a while now. always return nil, before it worked perfectly well.

Comment: NSDate *dateObj=[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];


What can be done to get proper output instead of "nil" ???

Answer (score 2):

`- (id)init` is not deprecated for NSDateFormatter in iOS4. That's an error in the documentation.

Comment: I was thinking this must be the case -- is this documented anywhere on Apple developer forums etc?

Answer (score 2):

[NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:] might work better

```
NSString *format = [NSDateFormatter
                   dateFormatFromTemplate:@"Mdjm"
                                  options:0
                                   locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

// "M/d h:mm a" // US English format returned for US locale

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:format];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Answer (score 2):

In iOS2.x and 3.x the NSDate description/datefromstring function returns: 
2010-09-24 17:30:00 - 0700

in iOS 4.1 it returns this: 
2010-09-25 00:30:00 GMT

You could submit a bug to apple. It doesn't even follow the specification which states that it should return 0000 for the offset. So not only does it not return local date, it also uses GMT instead of an offset. It appears that this new format isn't compatible with NSDateFormatter methods.

Also, I don't think it is an error in documentation. In the API Diff document, it lists that init is removed for NSDateFormatter.

Comment: Even more baffling, results vary if you change your device configuration from a 24-hour clock to a 12-hour clock :S