# NSDateFormater dateFromString:

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsdateformatter

```
NSDateFormatter *isoDateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[isoDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[isoDateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[isoDateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
NSString * str = [isoDateFormatter dateFromString:@"2008-12-31T12:00:00"]
```

on 4.0 IOS the above code i.e str is nill, on 3.0 IOS this works fine str is 2008-12-31.
How to overcome this issue?

Comment: The fact that this works on iOS 3 is more a bug than a feature, as dateFromString: does NOT return a NSString, but a NSDate. Your compiler is even telling you, with a warning. Read them.

Comment: copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212214/for-iphone-os-4-0-datefromstring-method-of-nsdateformatter-returns-nil

Answer (score 13):

It looks like you want to convert a date from one string format to another. To do that, you have to have to do it in two steps--formatting FROM string to NSSDate, then from that date to NSString.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateWriter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *dateReader = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateWriter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[dateReader setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *dateTmp = [dateReader dateFromString:@"2008-12-31T12:00:00"];
NSString *str = [dateWriter stringFromDate:dateTmp]
//str now contains "2008-12-31". 

//and don't forget!!!
[dateReader release];
[dateWriter release];
```

You could achieve the same result with one date formatter by reading, resetting the dateFormat and then writing, if you want. I just laid it out like this so it's easy to see the process.

Side note--I'm always forgetting to release NSDateFormatters. Clang and Instruments are always catching me leaking them. I guess I use them and it feels like they're done. They're not, though! So be smarter than me and remember to [NARC](http://vgable.com/blog/2010/05/19/n-a-r-c/) on your memory management!

Side note 2--Don't ignore compiler warnings. Your compiler is warning you about the invalid assignment you're doing, and you're ignoring that.

Answer (score 3):

dateFromString:
Returns a date representation of a given string interpreted using the receiver’s current settings.

```
- (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)string
```

Parameters
string
The string to parse.
Return Value
A date representation of string interpreted using the receiver’s current settings.

Availability
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
See Also

```
– getObjectValue:forString:range:error:
– stringFromDate:
```

Related Sample Code
URLCache
Declared In

```
NSDateFormatter.h
```

Read the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

The dateFromString returns an Date object not an NSString.

Comment: This answer was probably voted down because it seems to just be a restatement of the documentation. Had it simply said "dateFromString doesn't return a string; it returns a date", it would be more clearly relevant to the question.  I didn't downvote it, but it does bug me when people answer questions with "RTFM, you idiot"-style answers.